# Is it acceptable to ask summer camp administration to give other campers' families our contact information?

Tags: activities, friends, etiquette, usa

Our child had to miss the very last week of summer camp due to illness. Unfortunately, that last week was the time period when we planned to have the child ask their newly acquired friends for their contact information (parents' email or phone) to keep in contact after camp is over.

Obviously, the camp administration would not be willing or able to provide us with the other kids' families contact information for privacy reasons.

We are wondering if it's an acceptable practice to ask their help to - instead - do the reverse, and **ask the administration to provide the other children's parents with our contact information and a short note** that our kids were friends in camp and a cordial request to resume contact between them after camp if they wish to.

Comment: since practices may be locale dependent, this is USA.

Comment: Yup, this is something I've done for parents in the past re Scout Camp. Totally normal here in the UK at least.

Answer (score 5):

It is certainly a possibility, and something that I would do myself in this situation.  Be prepared for the camp to say no, of course; they may well simply not want to bother.  But, if you have a good relationship with them and they're an understanding group, they may be willing to help you.

I would prepare a note - either an email, if other business was done for this camp via email, or in stamped envelopes if not - and give it to the camp, and ask them to address and forward them on (explaining the reasons of course).  E-mail this may actually happen; if the camp had the policy to mass-email people for other things (schedules, etc.), they may well be willing to mass-emailed the note out.  Paper envelope it's probably harder to get them to do (as they'd have to hand-address them all), but perhaps you can get them to do one or two (if one of the other campmates for example was sufficiently social that he/she might have many other contacts).

I'm sure you were busy with dealing with your child's illness, of course, but in the future if this happens again and you're able to think of it, it's more likely to get aquiescence with this sort of thing if it involves handing the children themselves the notes, before camp finishes; we did a similar thing with pre-school last year, giving notes with our contact info to all of the kids at the school so we could link up over the summer.